# Google analytic revoketoken not revoking?

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am using google search console and google analytic service in my product. I am granting access for both service in same my google account and also i am granting access for each a service separately

When I am revoking access for google analytic alone it automatically google search console also revoked. I thing when i try to grant access for every service google mapped previously mapped service.

My question is i want to revoke google analytic only it will not affect google search console?
Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See google document](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer)

> If you revoke a token that represents a combined authorization, access to all of that authorization's scopes on behalf of the associated user are revoked simultaneously.